# JAVA concatenating double array => String(with special format)

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, concatenation

How do I format a String to convert a double array to the form: `[0.0, 2.4, 5.5, 6.3]`?

I am assigning double array elements to one string to have a string representation in the format above.

My code to change double array to a single string representation:

```
public String toString() {
    String toString="[";
     for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
         toString = toString + data[i] + ", ";
      }
    return toString + "]";
}
```

I am getting the array in the format [0.0, 2.4, 5.5, 6.3, ], which is not expected and wrong.

How can I get it formatted to [0.0, 2.4, 5.5, 6.3]?

I have tried to use `Arrays.toString()` method but, I am not allowed to use that in this project.

How should I change my code to have the desired format?

Comment: you can fix the result string or introduce some logic to avoid printing ',' if there are no more elements in the array. check substring and replace methods of the String class.

Answer (score 2):

You could stream the `data` array and let `Collectors.joining` do the heavy lifting:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.stream(data)
                 .mapToObj(Double::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
}
```

**Edit:**
If you can't stream the array, you could iterate it yourself and give special treatment to the first element, which is the only element that isn't preceded by a comma:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
    if (data.length > 0) {
        sb.append(data[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(", ").append(data[i]);
    }
    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but no JDK helper methods are allowed....

Answer (score 1):

You can stop your loop before the last element of the array and then manually add the last element to your string in the result. Like this:

```
if (data.length == 0) {
  return "[]";
}

int lastElementIndex = data.length - 1;
String result = "[";

for (int i = 0; i < lastElementIndex; i++) {
  result += data[i] + ", "; 
// or result += String.format("%.1f, ", data[i]); if you are allowed
}

return result + data[lastElementIndex] + "]"; 
// or String.format("%s%.1f]", result, data[lastElementIndex]);
```

Comment: @IanSeol I improved my answer a bit in the return statement and in the comments. I also added a check for an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

---

Just check the length of an array if it is greater than equal to one then concatenate it with toString and then start traversing from index 1 and return it.

```
 public String toString() {
    String toString="[";
    //check length of an array
     if(data.length >= 1){
        toString += data[0];
     }
    //start from 1st index
    for(int i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
        toString += ", " + data[i];
    }
    return toString + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if you are on last element and not add the `,` then:

```java
       public String toString2(double[] data) {
        String toString = "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (i == data.length - 1) {
                toString = toString + data[i];
            } else {
                toString = toString + data[i] + ", ";
            }
        }
        return toString + "]";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if-block to check for last element:

```
public String toString() {
    String toString = "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        toString = toString + data[i];
        if (i != data.length - 1) {
            toString = toString + ", ";
        }
    }
    return toString + "]";
}
```

Or alternatively add your separator before the elements except the first

```
public String toString() {
    String separator = "";
    String toString = "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        toString = toString + separator;
        toString = toString + data[i];
        separator = ", ";
    }
    return toString + "]";
}
```